# Parallelism in the Sentence

Tags: grammar, rhetoric

According to the rule of parallelism, is the following sentence correct

> *the spirit of winning should be more than the fear of being defeated*

Thanks!

Comment: Are you worried about the fact that *winning* is in active voice and *being defeated* is in passive voice? It's not perfect parallelism, but the King James Bible doesn't achieve perfect parallelism, either:  *Ask, and it shall be given you; seek, and ye shall find; knock, and it shall be opened unto you.*

Comment: It sounds fine to me apart from the use of 'more', on its own, as the comparative. More what? I recommend something like 'greater' or 'more inspiring'.

Comment: The sentence sounds fine to me. It has no grammatical errors and its meaning is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is parallel, but parity of voice would make it better.

> The `[noun]` of `[participle(active voice)]` is more than the `[noun]` of `[participle(passive voice)]`.

Perhaps

> The spirit of victory is more than the fear of defeat.

But then maybe it should be

> The `[emotion]` of `[noun]` is more than the `[emotion]` of `[noun]`.

Like maybe

> The thrill of victory is more than the fear of defeat.

But then it's starting to sound like the [Wide World of Sports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2AZH4FeGsc).

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is more an example of antithesis:

[Paralellism](http://literarydevices.net/parallelism/):

> - is the use of components in a sentence that are grammatically the same; or similar in their construction, sound, meaning or meter. Parallelism examples are found in literary works as well as in ordinary conversations.
>
>   - This method adds balance and rhythm to sentences giving ideas a smoother flow and thus can be persuasive because of the repetition it employs. For example, “Alice ran into the room, into the garden, and into our hearts.” We see the repetition of a phrase that not only gives the sentence a balance but rhythm and flow as well. This repetition can also occur in similar structured clauses e.g. “Whenever you need me, wherever you need me, I will be there for you.”

[Anthithesis](http://literarydevices.net/parallelism/):

> - is a kind of parallelism in which two opposite ideas are put together in parallel structures. Alexander Pope in his “An Essay on Criticism” uses antithetic parallel structure:
>
>   - “To err is human; to forgive divine.”
>   - "We must learn to live together as brothers or perish together as fools." - Martin Luther King, Jr.

(From literarydevices.net)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Peter Shor's comment beneath the OP's question, to the effect that a more consistent parallelism would involve maintaining the same voice or phrasing across the two parts of the expression. The easiest way to manage that in this case would be either to say

> The spirit of winning should be more than the fear of losing.

(pairing *winning* with *losing*) or

> The spirit of being victorious should be more than the fear of being defeated.

(pairing *being victorious* with *being defeated*). But grammatical correctness doesn't require you to uphold that level of consistent parallelism—or indeed any level of consistent parallelism at all, unless you take the step of attaching parallel phrasal limbs to the same trunk in a sentence. By doing so, you invite stricter scrutiny regarding the parallelism of the elements that you've introduced into your sentence, and readers may hold you to higher standard of consistency.

Comment: Note: _being victorious_ is not passive. It’s just _be_ with an adjective. I can’t think of any way to express winning in a passive construction (except perhaps _being lost against_, but that’s beyond clumsy well into the realm of bizarre).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I see that you're right, so I've tried to reword in a way that allows me to present the more balanced wordings without characterizing them as active or passive. Let me know if you think I should just bag this answer altogether.